# Computing predictive variance of the expected y in linear regression

Tags: regression, variance, predictive-models, linear-model

Given a labeled dataset $X$ $(x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ & $Y$ $(y_0, y_1, \dotsc, y_n)$ and learnt parameter $\hat{\theta}$ in linear regression model $y \sim \theta^{T} x$, what is the formula for calculating predictive variance of the expected value on a new data point? (e.g. $\hat{\theta} x_{new}$ ), given the labeled dataset?